# Are there kun'yomi ateji?

Tags: readings, ateji

In [a Linguistics SE question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8432/pronunciation-in-languages-from-east-asia-of-words-that-are-japanese-loanwords-i) on loanwords from Japanese into Chinese, it was said that the Chinese import the *kanji* and use their own reading thereof. So words in *kun'yomi* are unrecognizable in speech. It got me thinking about *ateji*: these must make messy loanwords. But since the *on'yomi* is close to the Chinese readings the Chinese and Japanese versions may sound alike so long as the *on'yomi* is used.

So, at long last, my question: are there *kun'yomi* *ateji*?

Comment: Do you mean, are there any loanwords from Japanese into Chinese which disregard the characters but only care about approximating the pronunciation? If so, there are quite a few in Taiwanese Mandarin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they exist. I'm assuming you don't mean things like 零{ゼロ} and things like 生憎{あいにく} or 可惜{あたら}, in which the Kanji means something relevant to the word, but the reading is unusual. Here are some examples I found on JMdict. I'm sure there are more.

> - 矢{や}っ張{ぱ}り
> - 目出度い {めでたい}
> - 藻掻く{もがく}

Comment: For 越幾斯, it's all on'yomi, albeit somewhat unusual: え from えつ, き, and す as the 唐音 version of the on'yomi.  It's possible the earliest pronunciation in Japanese might have been えっきす, in reflection of the Dutch _extract_, where (I think) the stress is on the first syllable, which might have parsed as a geminate //k// sound to Japanese speakers.